# How to get a gap in a circle in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am trying to create a small gap inside a circle I have created in draw.io but I do not see not even an eraser than I can just erase that area:

[image]

Is there a way I could do it here:

```
ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;shadow=0;strokeWidth=11;perimeterSpacing=0;spacingRight=1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `Circle` you should use an `Arc` or `Pie` or an `Arc+Circle` grouped.

`Left Sidebar` > `Basic` > `Arc` or `Pie`

[image: how to use an Arc or Pie shape in draw.io]

Comment: Out of curiosity. Which one did you use?